# Default value not being set in database column from application

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, websphere

I have an application running in websphere. I have configured the data source on the server and getting the datasource from jndi.
I am using Spring Jdbc and a couple of select statements are runnign just fine.

Now I have an insert statement that is running successfully from inside 'toad' but same insert statement is failing from the application.

```
java.sql.SQLException: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into ("SCHEMA1"."XYZ"."CREATED_BY")

CREATED_BY is a VARCHAR2 (30 Byte) with DEFAULT set to 'SYS_CONTEXT ('USERENV', 'OS_USER')'
```

**Note: I am not specifying the column in the insert statement. My statement is like the following:**

```
Insert into SCHEMA1.XYZ(some_column, another_column, is_active) values ('sadsf','sdfsdfsdf','Y')
```

I am using jdbcTemplate so essentially doing:

```
jdbcTemplate.update(theQuery);
```

I am configuring my datasource like the following:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean">
    <beans:property name="jndiName" value="jdbc/MyDatasource" />
</beans:bean>
```

Now I was expecting this to be coming from the username used while setting up JAAS - J2C authentication data for the data source.

I don't want to specify all the audit columns which can be easily autofilled with every query. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you want the default value to be used, you must not specify the column as part of the `INSERT` statement, or specify the keyword `DEFAULT` in the `VALUES` part.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. And its working inside toad but not working from the web application.

Comment: Then show us what the application does (e.g. the SQL Statements, the Java code...)

Comment: Updated with more information. But I strongly believe this is related to the fact that 'SYS_CONTEXT' has 'OS_USER' set when I am in toad but not when the query is coming from the application. Why, I don't know and how to do it right would probably answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [SYS_CONTEXT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/server.101/b10759/functions150.htm)

> **Predefined Parameters of Namespace USERENV**
> OS_USER     Operating system user name of the client process that initiated the database session.

There is also

> CLIENT_IDENTIFIER     Returns an identifier that is set by the application through the DBMS_SESSION.SET_IDENTIFIER procedure, the OCI attribute OCI_ATTR_CLIENT_IDENTIFIER, or the Java class Oracle.jdbc.OracleConnection.setClientIdentifier. This attribute is used by various database components to identify lightweight application users who authenticate as the same database user.
>
> SESSION_USER  Database user name by which the current user is authenticated. This value remains the same throughout the duration of the session.

I'm not familiar with Oracle authentication, but maybe one of the latter is more suitable for your task.

Comment: That is exactly what I am doing. And its working inside toad but not working from application.

Comment: Many Thanks! Brilliant! SESSION_USER is what should have been used in the first place. It represents the original intent and works.

Comment: Also on a side note, I also found out that the reason OS_USER was null was because of an Oracle bug (#3735857) in ojdbc14.jar version 10.2.0.1.0 and some other versions also. Bug says "Symptom: The OSUSER column is null in V$SESSION when using the thin JDBC driver 10.2.0.1." and Solution as "Apply Patch 4677125 to a 10.2.0.1.0 JDBC driver." - Source - http://primavera.zxlm.cn/kb/prim73199